# Rearrange the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below array:

```
Array
(
[Support Services - 1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [team] => Delivery Excellence
                [count] => 4
                [location] => Location1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [team] => Delivery Excellence
                [count] => 1
                [location] => Location2
            )

    )
```

)

I want the array to be rearranged in the following pattern for Excel download

[image: Required format]

I have the header array as follow:

```
$finalArrayHeader = array('Department'); 
foreach($location_data as $key=>$value){ 
    array_push($finalArrayHeader,$value['name']); 
} 
array_push($finalArrayHeader,'Grand Total');
```

As the locations are dynamic

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What have you already tried and what didn’t work?

Comment: I have the header array as follow:
$finalArrayHeader = array('Department');
   foreach($location_data as $key=>$value){
    array_push($finalArrayHeader,$value['name']);
   }
   array_push($finalArrayHeader,'Grand Total');
As the locations are dynamic.

Comment: You should edit the question and put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in few steps.

- Access all indexes one by one
- Based on location if condition you need to start printing row of table
- Then Access sub indexes of that main index and print all values

Further, please share your tries so I can guide you more.